# PHP/MySQLi query "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This code successfully gets all the posted data and stores it in the appropriate variables (I've already checked them all), but updating the information in the database is causing a problem and I can't figure out why. It is saying that bind_param() is being called on a non-object. The ID variable was set earlier in the program and contains the correct data. I was thinking maybe there's a problem in the query itself?

Update: Everything works perfectly fine when the bind_param line is removed, so the error is almost definitely in that line.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") // if the form has been submitted
{


    $newusername = $_POST["newusername"]; // get new email
    $newemail = $_POST["newemail"]; // get new username
    $newabout = $_POST["newabout"];
    $newbooks = $_POST["newbooks"];
    $newauthors = $_POST["newauthors"];
    $newmovies = $_POST["newmovies"];
    $newtv = $_POST["newtv"];

    $success = true;


    if ($conn->connect_error) // if there's a problem connecting to the db send error message
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        $success = false;
    }


    if ($success)
    {
        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Users SET Username = ?, Email = ?, About = ?, Books = ?, Authors = ?, Movies = ?, TV = ? WHERE ID = ?"); // prepare query
        $statement->bind_param('ssssssss', $newusername, $newemail, $newabout, $newbooks, $newauthors, $newmovies, $newtv, $id); // bind parameters for query
        $statement->execute();

    }

}
```

Comment: If `$conn->prepare()` fails (ie returns false), what happens to the rest of your code? Is `$statement` an object or a non-object?

Comment: Have you tried using `mysqli_stmt_error()` ?

Comment: Have you checked to see what "$statement" is returned as?

Comment: POST array / HTML form might have failed also. Use error reporting and post your form. Error reporting would have spotted that undefined `$id` variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: where...........is................. `$id`...............defined? are you paying attention up here, rather than just in the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You have:

`$statement->bind_param('sssssss', $newusername,....`

There are 7 "s" in there, but 8 fields and variables.

Just add one more 's': `bind_param('ssssssss', ...`

Comment: There are eight parameters. I added another "s", it's still giving me the same problem.

Comment: @Arty I don't know if that's the complete script, but I don't see the $id variable anywhere (before the UPDATE statement, that is)